# If a cisco switch is on the other side of a wire when it's plugged into a cable tester; is that dangerous?

Tags: switch

[This cable tester](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085LPN71C) has numbered fobs that plug in the other end of an Ethernet port and report back which number they are;

If the cable tester is accidentally plugged into a switch port when the test is sent; will it just be a dropped packet; or will it cause hardware damage?

Comment: Methods differ, there's no standard for that. Usually I'd say those things are designed with a bit of common sense but you should really consult the manual.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that unit, but I would assume Klein would build a tester that can sense a live line. (with LLDP/CDP enabled, it could tell you the switch, and port.)

Answer (score 0):

From the linked shop:

> HUB BLINK MODE: Hub blink mode enables the identification of port locations on a hub or switch, facilitating efficient network management

That pretty much guarantees that plugging into a live switch port is a normal mode of testing and nothing breaks. They even show that test in the video.

Comment: From the manual: Do not initiate HUB BLINK MODE on a PoE Port.

Comment: Does the voltage warning tell you that it is a PoE Port and that you should not run the HUB BLINK MODE ?